# C++/GLEW strange artefacts when drawing a 3D cube

Tags: opengl, c++, glew

I'm working on a bad 3D game engine in C++ with the help of GLEW, GLM and GLFW. I made the engine halfway through in 2D, but I wanted to rewrite it for 3D.
I skipped the part with the per-vertex color, and just set the color solid red with the fragment shader. But I have [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRKJjYjEkiA&feature=youtu.be) strange, flickering artefacts appearing. I don't have any clue where this comes from...

**Note that the flickering got much worse while recording.**

**EDIT:**

How I set up my window:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DOUBLEBUFFER, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

glfwWindow = glfwCreateWindow(int(size.x), int(size.y), title.c_str(), NULL, NULL); /* Creates window (GLFW)*/
glfwMakeContextCurrent(glfwWindow); //Binds OpenGL

setClearColor(color);

/* GLEW Stuff */
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
int glewState = glewInit();
if(glewState != GLEW_OK){ /* If glewInit() fails */
    throw(AmethystException("Could not glewInit(). GLEW Error: " + std::string((const char*)glewGetErrorString(glewState))));
}

//TODO: Move openGL related shit out of here
glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);                                 /* Transparency */
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); /* Transparency */
```

And how I clear every frame at the end:

```
int errorCode = glGetError();
if(errorCode != GL_NO_ERROR){
    Logger::error("GLEW error (" + std::to_string(errorCode) + ")");
}

glfwPollEvents();
keyboard.pollKeyInformation(glfwWindow);

if(glfwWindowShouldClose(glfwWindow)){
    Logger::info("Received close request", 3);
    return false;
}else{
    glfwSwapBuffers(glfwWindow);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    return true;
}
```

Is there anything that stands out?
I also added a second [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GKAR5BvMcc).
There should only be solid red cubes.

Comment: Do you clear the depth buffer?

Comment: @Bálint If `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` is what you mean, yea.

Comment: You should show your code, we can't help you like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what it was. My fault for using code I don't fully understand what it does.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

This was the cause for the flickering. Removing them fixes everything. I don't know why tho. Those two lines are back from my unfinished 2D engine.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is a partially rendered image.

The flicker is due to the glClear() command erasing what you just drew to the front buffer (the window) and the squares are due to the way the GPU draws its triangles tile by tile.

You are rendering to the front buffer which is being displayed.

You need to render to the back buffer and swap the buffers (possibly with vsync) or an off-screen frame buffer and then copy it to the front buffer (no vsync possible).

Create a context with both a front and back buffer, use `glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK)` to draw to the back buffer and then call your platform's swap buffer command (`wglSwapLayerBuffers` on windows, `glXSwapBuffers` on X11, `glSwapAPPLE` on OSX, etc).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. If thats the problem, I'll accept your answer! :)

Comment: Hmm I am swapping the buffers. I guess that I always draw to the front one.. Where exactly do I have to put `glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK)` to work as expected? I cannot find any documentation online :/

Comment: If you don't create your context with a back buffer there will only be a front buffer and swapping the buffers will do nothing. GLFW needs you to specify GLFW_DOUBLEBUFFER in order to create a context/window with double buffering.

Comment: Sadly, doublebuffering is already enabled by default in GLFW. And even if I enable it afterwards, no change, sadly.

Comment: I'll just refer to https://bitbucket.org/Kiryu144/amethyst3d/src . The important classes are main, window and entity. And sorry for the poor quality code. Most of it is _working pseudo code_ for me to get into 3D stuff.